# Flutter Show Modal Bottom Sheet after build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

As the title says, I have a String parameter and when I load the Home Stateful Widget I would like to open this bottom sheet if the parameter is not null.

As I understood I can't call `showModalBottomSheet()` in the build function of the Home widget because it can't start building the bottom sheet while building the Home Widget, so, is there a way to call this immediately after the Home Widget is built?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the solutions might be using addPostFrameCallback function of the SchedulerBinding instance. This way you could call showModalBottomSheet after the Home widget is built.

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          //Your builder code
        },
      );
    });

    //Return widgets tree for Home
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context, 
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: Text('heyooo'),
          );
        }
      );
    });
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```